# Add multiple columns from different tables in SELECT statement using a GROUP BY with just one parameter

Tags: sql, group-by

I've created the code below. The output I'm looking for is the latest details for each employee based on the "Date Updated" column (each time details are saved for an employee a new row is added to the "Employee" table). The issue I'm having is that I don't know how to include other columns to the select statement without adding them to the GROUP BY. I've seen similar posts to this but as the "CompanyName" column exists in the "Company" table I'm finding it difficult to write

```
SELECT
Company.CompanyName AS [Company Name],
Employee.EmployeeID AS [Employee ID],
Employee.DateUpdated AS [Date Updated],
MAX(Employee.DateUpdated) AS [MAX Date Updated]
FROM (dbo.Company
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Employee ON (Company.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID)
)
GROUP BY
Employee.EmployeeID
```

The table I'd like to see would be similar to the below

```
Company Name | Employee ID | Date Updated
    ABC           0001        01/01/2014
    ABC           0530        01/04/2013
    ABC           2001        01/01/1999
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is basically okay, except for the `group by` clause.  You need `CompanyName` there.  That said, you can improve the query:

```
SELECT c.CompanyName AS [Company Name], e.EmployeeID AS [Employee ID],
       MAX(e.DateUpdated) AS [MAX Date Updated]
FROM dbo.Company c JOIN
     dbo.Employee e
     ON c.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
GROUP BY c.CompanyName, e.EmployeeName;
```

The changes:

- Fixed the `group by` clause.
- Added table aliases that are abbreviations for table names.  These make the query easier to write and read.
- Changed the `left join` to an inner join.  The left join seems unnecessary.  Why would an `employeeid` not match in the two tables, if the data is properly maintained?

Comment: Many thanks Gordon - If there are other fields in either table that I would like to select, is it just a case of adding them in the SELECT and GROUP BY?

Comment: @user2547766  . . . Yes.  That is the easiest solution.

Comment: Thanks again. It's all making a bit more sense!